# fast cholesky factorization of an array of matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab

I would like to know how to perform a fast Cholesky factorization on an array of matrices. Suppose I have a 3x3x1000 array A of pd matrices and would like to find cholesky factorzations of these 1000 matrices. I know I can easily write something like

```
for n=1:1000
    cl(:,:,n) = chol(A(:,:,n);
end
```

However, because of the for loop this is a fairly slow procedure. Is there any way of speeding up this and avoiding the 'for' loop altogether. Any ideas are appreciated.

One idea I had was to transform the array into a block diagonal matrix and take the chol factorization of it and hence would have a block matrix of cholesky factorizations, however I do not know yet how to perform this without having to create a full 3000x3000 matrix (and such matrix sizes could make the procedure slow as well). I am not familiar with using sparse matrices on matlab and maybe that could be one of the solutions.

Comment: Are you sure that the loop is the cause? What you are experiencing is probably just the time taken to compute 1000 Cholesky factorizations; that _has_ to be slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is indeed a potential of gaining some computational time by constructing a sparse matrix as you described (probably, because matlab understands the nice block structure of such matrix):

```
N=10000;
D=3;
A=zeros(D,D,N);
for n=1:N, a=rand(D); A(:,:,n)=a'*a; end

tic
cl=zeros(D,D,N);
for n=1:N, cl(:,:,n)=chol(A(:,:,n)); end
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.0919061 seconds.

B=zeros(D*N);
for n=1:N, B(D*(n-1)+1:D*(n-1)+D,D*(n-1)+1:D*(n-1)+D)=A(:,:,n); end
C=sparse(B);
tic, cl2 = chol(C); toc
% Elapsed time is 0.006457 seconds.
```

Now the question is if how to construct the sparse matrix C. The method described above is very slow and needs a lot of memory if D and N are larger (I guess, in your case D and N are larger than in your example). In general, to construct a sparse matrix in matlab you have to specify (1) its dimension, i.e. DN x DN in your case (2) all nonzero elements using arrays rowinds, colinds, values (all of the same length) such that C(rowinds(k),colinds(k))=values(k), i.e.

```
values = A(:);
C=sparse(rowinds,colinds,values,D*N,D*N);
```

The question is how do you construct the arrays rowinds and colinds, which in your case will look like rowinds = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 7 8 8 8 9 9 9 ... DN DN DN] and colinds = [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 4 5 6 4 5 6 7 8 9 7 8 9 ... DN-2 DN-1 DN]. Here is a possible solution

```
tic,
temp = repmat(1:D*N,D,1); rowinds = temp(:);
cols = zeros(D,D*N);
for j=1:D
  tempj = repmat(j:D:D*N-D+j,D,1); cols(j,:)=tempj(:)';
end
colinds=cols(:);
C=sparse(rowinds,colinds,A(:),D*N,D*N);
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.017159 seconds.
tic,
cl2 = chol(C);
toc
% Elapsed time is 0.006926 seconds.
```

I believe, there should be a faster way to construct the arrays of indices.

Comment: Your block matrices in C are transposed versions of what they should be. This is easily fixed by swapping your `rowinds` and `colinds` values.